# NMAP not showing all live hosts

Tags: nmap, arp

I have a live host on 192.168.0.151 on my local network. I know it's live since I've set it up with a  static IP and also if pinged, I get a reply.

The weird thing is when I run  `nmap -sP 192.168.0.151` I can see that the host is up indeed, but when running `nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/24` it goes straight pass it and shows that it's down. I've tried this same exact thing using `arp` and `scapy` and I seem to consistently have the same issue where I cannot for some reason specify an IPv4 range to do an arp request on.

What I do in scapy is:

```
#/usr/bin/env python
import scapy.all as scapy
scappy.arping("192.168.0.1/24")
```

Comment: This is an ongoing issue with Nmap due to some unusual behavior by targets, but we have been unable to determine a good approach to fixing it. Please comment on our Github issues page, especially if  you can provide a packet capture of a scan that does not show the target up, but which does include an ARP reply from the target: https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/92

Comment: Are you saying that scapy can't find it either?

Comment: I think there is an extra `p` in `scappy.arping`. Can't edit due to six character minimum change limitation.

Comment: Yeah that's just a typo but it's fixed and yeah.. Scapy doesn't really find it either

Comment: Have you tried: nmap -sn 192.168.0.1/24